# How to rotate a loaded image object before scaling it?

Tags: bitmap, image-rotation, easeljs, createjs

I'm using EaselJS with an image file loaded into a bitmap. I'm having troubles with getting it to rotate in the order I'd like. Here is an example of what I'm working with:

```
var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap("image.png");
bitmap.rotation = -10;
bitmap.scaleX = 1.5;
bitmap.scaleY = 1.2;
```

What's happening is it's rotating the scaled image and not the original. *Any ideas how to rotate the original image and then scale it?* I want to do it programmatically and not mess with the raw image file, actually that's not an option with what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Using createjs.Bitmap to transform a DisplayObject will never manipulate the original image, if you want to manipulate the original image you would have to go through a native `HTMLCanvas` or `HTMLImage`

Here's an example how to scale an original image(adding rotation should be just 3-4additional lines), you would have to create your createjs.Bitmap with the returned reference of course, and not with the original image-source-string.

```
function nativeScale(img, scale)
{
    var dst_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    dst_canvas.width = Math.max(1,img.width * scale);
    dst_canvas.height = Math.max(1,img.height * scale);
    var dst_ctx = dst_canvas.getContext('2d');

    dst_ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,dst_canvas.width,dst_canvas.height);

    if ( typeof canvas.toDataURL == "undefined" ) return dst_canvas;

    var img = new Image();
    img.width = canvas.width;
    img.height = canvas.height;
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return img;
}
```

I hope that helps.
And as an additional note: This will **not** work when executed through a local file-system, you will only be able to run this through a Web-Server (Online or XAMPP e.g.) due to the browser's security-settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that certainly does allow for altering the image before using it with createjs. I also found there is another way that is a little more compact. You can load bitmaps into containers. If you modify the bitmaps scale, then rotate the container it seems to have the same effect.

Comment: hm, then I'm not entirely sure what exactly you were looking for, because your solution also will just affect that very bitmap-instance, not the original image - But you've found a solution, so that's what matters ;)